# What is the use of ? in grep command.. And practical use

Tags: regex, grep

I tried to find the actual practical use of ? i.e. for e.g. "egrep a? filename" but was not able to find any.. It returns all results..

So, Please help me out wherein i could know the actual use of egrep ? command..

If i use 'a?', it returns all result i.e. strings or lines. which has 0 a's, 1 a's, 2 a's and so on.. i.e. i am not able to find the use of the same..

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Say you wanted to match numeric assignment expressions like this in a script:

```
x=1234
```

where some numbers are negative and have a minus sign:

```
x=-5678
```

You could use this:

```
grep -E "x=-?[0-9]+" *
```

The question mark makes the minus optional.

(I don't think plain grep supports `?` or `+`, hence `-E`).

Comment: I understood it.. Thanks a lot.. 
Also what does 'egrep a? filename' will do actually.. If you can put it in words..

Comment: @RB: `egrep a? filename` will match every line.  It's not useful on its own.

Comment: Regular GNU grep (without the -E) supports the `?` but you must escape it.

`echo "color" | grep "colou\?r"`

Should return `color`.

Answer (score 11):

`?` is not a metacharacter in basic `grep`, so if you're grepping for `a?`, you are in fact grepping for `a` followed by a question mark.

If you were using `egrep` (aka `grep -E`), then answers indicating that `?` is a zero-or-one-of-previous-entity regex metacharacter would be correct.

Comment: Yes sir, u are right.. but my doubt lies here itself the it will be always true to have previous character occuring 0 or 1 time.. so what's the use of ? then,, I need to know where this ? is useful.. Otherwise we would have use * also, for doing the same thing, as it is returning the same results.

Comment: Yes, `a?` by itself is nonsensical to search for because it will always match.  It only makes sense as part of a larger regex.

Comment: Can you give any example of such an reg-expression.. where i can know one use of ?..

Comment: He meant a? = "" or "a".  In this case everything matches "". You are searching for one or zero characters of one character which would also match anything.

Comment: I have just given an example, to convey my question effectively.. But what i need is actual implementation use of "egrep ?". Is there any reg-expr from where i could find the actual use of it..

Comment: Did you read my comment? I gave you one

Comment: If you want to match `a` and `aa` but not `aaa` or `aaaa` etc, you would want the regex `aa?`.

Comment: @chaos: No, that's simply wrong.  `aa?` will match `a`, `aa`, `aaa` and `aaaa`.  The `?` doesn't limit what comes after it.  Please try these things out before posting them.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Hm, let's see if I can state this in a politic fashion.  What you're not recognizing is the difference between a regex *matching* a sequence and it returning positive for a string *containing* that sequence.  If `aa?` *matched* `aaaa`, then `aa?b` would match `aaaab`.

Comment: @chaos: Ah, OK, understood.  For what it's worth, I don't think your comment *If you want to match `a` and `aa` but not `aaa` or `aaaa` etc, you would want the regex `aa?`* makes that clear.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Yeah, perhaps not.  Hopefully this additional commentary will have clarified it.

Comment: I think the canonical example RB was looking for is "ab?c" will match "ac" or "abc".

Answer (score 4):

It's a single character search, matching one or zero of the character before it.

Note: you need to escape the ? by using a \ first: \?.

Comment: Why the downvote? :/

Comment: Not my downvote, but I don't think your answer makes any sense.  Your regex is `i-?` but you talk about matching `i+j`. And if you meant to say `i+?` then that will still match `i++`.  The `?` doesn't limit what comes *after* the match, so `i+?` will happily match `i++`.

Answer (score 1):

In regex speak, a? means 0 or 1 'a's. So if you search for a string that has 0 or 1 a's in it, you'll get everything.  A place where it would be useful is matching positive integers:

```
/^\+?\d+$/
```

which plays out as

```
^: beginning of line
\+: + sign
?: 0 or 1 of previous character
\d: digit
+: one or more of previous character
$: end of line
```

and would match both `+123` and `456`

Have a look at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for more info on using regex's.